# Create Directory in server

Tags: asp.net

I save file to server with below code but when i want to create folder says : "URI formats are not supported"

```
//Save File
string folderPath = MapPath(@"Attachment\");
FileUpload1.SaveAs(folderPath + name);

//Directory
Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath+@"\111");
```

Comment: What is the value of folderPath?

Comment: I don't check it,but it's correct because i can save file

Comment: Assumptions are the mother of all things that possibly can go wrong. Check its value...

Comment: D:\Crm\crm\Attachment\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check exist before

```
string folderPath =Server.MapPath("Attachment");
if(!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
   Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
```

*side note:*

when you concat paths better to use `Path.Combine`

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Path.Combine(folderPath , name));
```

OR try with

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(new Uri(folderPath+@"\111").LocalPath);
```

since you get "URI formats are not supported" error message